# How to set Page wise Restriction in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, multiselect

I am making one extension which displays header notification at top of page,
I am make one multi select field in `system.xml` in which user select pages in which he/she want to display Notification. For example if user select **HomePage** and **About us** page then notification display in only this two page. How to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No need to create Attribute**

1. Create Static Block
2. Assign block to widget
3. Set widget positon where it should be display

[image]